# CUDA kernel and explicit namespace of math functions

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm working on a project where there are multiple definitions of basic math functions (cos, sin, exp, log, sqrt, ...) overloaded for various objects. It is not uncommon that I include multiple headers with such definitions (e.g. `<cmath>`, `<cuda.h>` and my own headers). To be completely sure that the right implementation is used, I want to explicitly write out the namespace, e.g. `std::sqrt()`. That made me wonder two related things:

**Q:** How do I make sure that it I use the `<cuda.h>` implementation of a particular function, i.e. is it possible to write out the namespace explicitly?

**Q:** Will I run into issues using e.g. `std::sqrt()` in a CUDA kernel (say performance issues, since it is typically a host function)?

Comment: Note that you can define your own namespace, and place inline wrapper functions in it - even making them templated, so you can control the exact behavior for each input type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside cuda kernels you can only use functions with `__device__` attribute. This guarantees that nothing from `std::` or `cmath` will be used.

```
error: calling a constexpr __host__ function("sqrt") from a __global__ function("kernel") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.
```

Comment: This is useful, thank you. I guess it gets more tricky in the situation with a function defined with both the `__host__` and `__device__` attributes - there we rely on that it automatically knows which implementation to use?

Comment: On the host side, yes, symbols can mix. But if you don't use `using namespace`, then compiler will produce multiple definitions error. Inside cuda kernels still only functions that have `__device__` will be available.

Comment: Do I interpret it correctly then that for a function with both `__host__` and `__device__` attributes, presents a rare case when `using namespace std` is preferable (in order to safeguard that there is errors for the host implementation)?

Comment: It's general `c++` advice. Do not use `using namespace std` if you are not sure that another implementation will have names collision. Then you will have to provide full namespace path and this will avoid shadowing.

Comment: So is it possible to specify that a `__host__ __device__` function uses e.g. std for a host implementation, without breaking a device implementation?

Comment: yes, you can use `#ifdef __CUDACC__` inside the function to have different behaviour on host and device.

Comment: is this answer correct? Doesn't it contradict [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058821/why-does-stdsin-work-in-the-cuda-kernel?noredirect=1&lq=1) ans?