# Why does std::sin() work in the CUDA kernel?

Tags: c++, cuda

The following code compiles (with `nvcc test.cu -o test`) and runs without error, meaning that `std::sin()` does work on the device:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>

__global__ void map_sin(double* in, double* out, int n) {
  const int i = blockIdx.x * 512 + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n) {
    out[i] = std::sin(in[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
  const int n = 1024;
  std::vector<double> in(n), out(n);
  std::iota(in.begin(), in.end(), 1.);

  double *in_, *out_;
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&in_), n * sizeof(double));
  cudaMemcpy(in_, in.data(), n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&out_), n * sizeof(double));

  map_sin<<<n / 512, 512>>>(in_, out_, n);

  cudaMemcpy(out.data(), out_, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(in_);
  cudaFree(out_);

  for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    assert(std::abs(out[i] - std::sin(in[i])) < 1e-3);
  }
}
```

Why? How? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60356749/905845), CUDA kernels are supposed to be able to call only `__device__` functions. Is `std::sin()` somehow marked `__device__` when compiling with `nvcc`?

Comment: Which CUDA version did you use? I can confirm that this code builds and runs just fine with CUDA 9.2. The proximate cause is that `std::sin` is translated into plain `sin` in the source code sent to the device-code compiler (by inspection of the intermediate file retained with `--keep`). Whether that is a documented feature or just "happens to work" in recent CUDA versions I do not know at this time.

Comment: I'm using CUDA 10.2, and talonmies' answer mentions 11.1, so this behavior is here on three major versions of CUDA.

Comment: The [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#mathematical-functions-appendix) states: "The reference manual lists, along with their description, **all the functions of the C/C++ standard library mathematical functions** that are supported in device code". (emphasis added) So that seems fairly explicit. The [restriction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-library) on standard library usage in device code allows for such exceptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is `std::sin()` somehow marked `__device__` when compiling with nvcc?

No. It is apparently  replaced with `sin` by the CUDA front end parser in the code which is passed to the GPU compiler, and then the normal [overload mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63065825/681865) is used to ensure the correct GPU math library function is substituted. The code which the GPU compiler sees is (nvcc version 11.1.74):

```
__global__ __var_used__ void _Z7map_sinPdS_i( double *in, double *out, int n)
{
    {
        int __cuda_local_var_31644_13_non_const_i;
        __cuda_local_var_31644_13_non_const_i = ((int)(((blockIdx.x) * 512U) + (threadIdx.x)));
        if (__cuda_local_var_31644_13_non_const_i < n)
        {
        (out[__cuda_local_var_31644_13_non_const_i]) = (sin((in[__cuda_local_var_31644_13_non_const_i])));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are no namespaces.

> Why? How?

It isn't documented and I have no special insider information on implementation details, but I am guessing that for the contents of `<cmath>`  (where the [CUDA math library](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html) has an implementation of everything defined in the C++11 standard), the namespace is just stripped off and everything works. For other C++ standard library functions, that can't happen and you will get a compile failure of the sort you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Accepting this answer because it shows the "How". If another answer manages to point at some official documentation of this behavior, or comes from someone with (justified) "insider information", I may change the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Perhaps I didn't make it clear, but the magic bit is the handling/stripping of the std namespace. Obviously the C standard math library requires nothing special where there are overloads available through templating But the namespace stripping/transformation is the undocumented bit AFAIK

Comment: sorry, I put my comment in the wrong place.  I had intended my comment to be mostly orthogonal to your answer, which does not really have documentation in view.  I agree the implementation is not documented.